# Visual Studio - Xamarin forms application not deploying onto iOS through "Pair to Mac"

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that has suddenly stopped deploying onto the iOS simulator when I use the "Pair to Mac" option on VS 2019. VS pairs to the mac with absolutely no problems, and it gives me the option to pick my simulator here: [image]

However, when I click to deploy the app, the build and deploy stops almost immediately, and this is shown in the output.
[image]

It doesn't even look like it's trying to deploy it! I don't know why this has happened as it used to work with no issues until recently.

(Edit) I have the latest version of Visual Studio Community 2019 (16.8.4) and Xcode (12.3).

Comment: Did you update the VS recently ? You could post the issue to  **Help->Send Feedback ->Report a problem** .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I've just posted the issue thanks. Do you think it is a bug in the version then?

Comment: Make sure that the version of Xcode is up to date .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT yes, Xcode is up to date

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I tried to go back to an earlier version and the error is still there

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, I'm currently using Testflight in order to deploy on my own iPhone but it takes so long. If you have an Iphone this is a good alternative if you have to test now